# Using USB to Parallel Port, Send an 8-bit data of Assembly Code

Tags: usb, assembly, converter, parallel-port

For educational purposes, our professors have DB25 ports on our laboratory rooms, and of course we can only simulate our assembly codes in there

Our professor said that it might not be possible to control 8 LEDs (terminal `D0-D7`) using a USB to Parallel Port(DB25) Converter,

We're simulating, for example, 
We're sending binary information to the port that would do this:

```
D0 On
D1 On
D2 Off
D3 On
D4 On
D5 Off
D6 Off
D7 On
```

It would be `mov al, 11011001b`, as I've said we've done this on PC's that have available DB25 port

Is it possible to send an 8-bit data through a USB to Parallel Port(DB25) Converter?

Comment: The OP of that question doesn't specify anything and there's no marked solution

Comment: -1 There was a good __answer__ to the earlier question, although it was not the solution you are hoping for. That doesn't mean the answer is wrong or that asking again will change things. This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible (unless maybe if you are a guru-level windows hacker).

The reason is that such a converter creates a virtual PRINTER, and there is no windows API to send a byte to a printer.

With an usb-to-serial converter the situation is different: for this windows creates a virtual PORT and there are API calls to send a byte to such a port.

Wouter